# PHP FILTER_INPUT not receiving text input

Tags: php

I'm running an Apache server on MAMP on macOSX. The problem I've occurred is that every variable is receiving the filter_input() but the last one, "param". I've tried using $_POST['param']; to no avail. I've restarted the Apache server but nothing has changed. I'm sure it's a syntax error, but all the other questions on here are unrelated and unhelpful. The one "PHP form not receiving inputs" was no help at all. Any help is appreciated :)

EDIT: I've realized using filter_input(INPUT_POST, "param") was not needed since I don't provide a filter, and that $_POST["param"] is a more acceptable method.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Code Writer (JAVA)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Code Writer (JAVA)</h1>
    </center>
    <form action="backwards.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Enter visibility level (public/private/etc)</label>
            <input type="text" name="first"><br>
            <label>Static Method? Y/N</label>
            <input type="text" name="static"><br>
            <label>Enter return type (int/double/etc)</label>
            <input type="text" name="return"><br>
            <label>Enter method name?</label>
            <input type="text" name="method"><br>
            <label>Paramaters, if any</label>
            <input type="text" name="param"><br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>backwards.php</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        #Gather inputs
        $first = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "first");
        $static = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "static");
        $return = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "return");
        $method = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "method");
        $param = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "param");

        #Add to $output
        $output = $first . " ";
        if ($static == "Y") {
            $output .= "static" . " ";
        }
        $output .= $return . " ";
        $output .= $method . "(";
        $output .= $param;
        $output .= ") {} \n";

        #Print $output
        print($output);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `filter_input(INPUT_POST, "first");` this is silly as it does nothing since you don't provide a filter. It's no different then using `_POST['first']`.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show if you put it at the top of backwards.php?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out that right after running the website with @John Conde's comment "var_dumb($_POST)", it started working. Removing the var_dump and it still works, although I am confused as to why. The matter is resolved, but I'm still confused as to why it works now, and not before.